# encode angular template in ASP.NET mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, templates

I am trying to encode this simple attribute...

```
var url = Url.Action("Method", new { code = "{{item.code}}" });
<a ng-href="@url">link</a>
```

I need the angular template delimiters output by the MVC framework intact.
The only thing that seems to work is this:

```
@Html.Raw("/a/b/c/d/{{item.code}}")
```

The problem with this approach is that I loose all the utility gained from `Url.Action`. I want to make use of the routing where possible.

There should be a way to encode `{{item.code}}` so that it is not transformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've similar problem w jsView. That is how it works for me. Extension method:

```
public static IHtmlString RawLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string link)
{
    return helper.Raw(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(link));
}

public static IHtmlString RawActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper helper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues)
{
    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
    return RawLink(helper, urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues));
}
```

Usage:

```
<a href="@Html.RawLink(Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id = "{{:Id}}" }))">Some link</a>
```

or:

```
<a href="@Html.RawActionLink("Action", "Controller", new { id = "{{:Id}}" })">Some link</a>
```